# Stopping time, why $E[S_{\nu}]=\mu E[\nu]$?

Tags: probability, martingales, stopping-times

Let $Y_1,Y_2,....$ be iid random variables with mean $\mu$, let $S_n =\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i$. Let $F_n=\sigma(Y_1,...,Y_n)$. Let $\nu$ be a stopping time s.t. $E[\nu]<\infty$. Why $E[S_{\nu}]=\mu E[\nu]$?

Comment: Have you tried to condition by $\nu$? And get something like $\mathbb{E}[S_\nu]=\sum_{i\geqslant 0}\mathbb{E}[S_n|\nu=n]\mathbb{P}[\nu=n] $ where $\mathbb{E}[S_n|\nu=n]$ would be equal to $n\mathbb{E}[Y_1]$ to obtain $\mathbb{E}[S_\nu]= \mu  \sum_{i\geqslant 0}n \mathbb{P}[\nu=n] = \mu \mathbb{E}[\nu]$ ?

Comment: For reference, this is called Wald's equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation

Answer (score 1):

Using the identity $E[Y]=E[E[Y|X]]$:

$$E[S_{\nu}]=E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{\nu}Y_i\right] = E\left[E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{\nu}Y_i\Bigg|\nu\right]\right] = E\left[\nu E[Y_k|\nu]\right]= E[\nu \mu]=\mu E[\nu]$$

As

$$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{\nu}Y_i\Bigg|\nu\right] = \nu E[Y_k|\nu]$$

because once the value of $\nu$ is known, the stochastic sum is just an ordinary sum. And since all $Y_k$ are identically distributed and their distribution is independent of $\nu$, we have that for all $k$

$$E[Y_k|\nu]=E[Y_1|\nu]=E[Y_1] = \mu$$

Comment: Of course, the heart of the matter is *why* $$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{\nu}Y_i\Bigg|\nu\right]= \nu E[Y_1|\nu]$$ (replaced $Y_i$ by $Y_1$, I guess this is what you mean?) and *why* $$E[Y_1|\nu]=\mu$$ two steps you say nothing about.

Comment: "As Did remarked in the comment" Sorry but I did not "remark" this, I merely pointed that the assertions in your post were not proven. They still are not.